# Use Nominatim db to connect with any OSM router/direction engine

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, openstreetmap, maproute, nominatim

I was just wondering if anyone knows about how to work OSM routing/direction/navigation engine ([OSM Router Engine Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing)) with existing local Nominatim posgresql DB.

I have already installed Nominatim and its relevant DB in my server and since its huge, I dont want another copy of the same huge thing in my server.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominatim has its own database format. You can't use it for routing. The same applies to routing databases and rendering databases, they usually have different schemes optimized for their particular use case.

Considuer using smaller [extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) if you don't have much disk space available. You can [split them into even smaller areas](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Splitting_one_big_file_into_different_geographical_regions), for examble by using osmium tool.

Comment: No, please don't :)